# Yii2-user: How to create admin user in batch mode?

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

When deploying my application there is of course always an `admin` user.

How can I create such an `admin` user as a first user without any interaction ...

- ... by means of SQL?
- ... using a Yii2-migration?

Comment: the simplest  way is the migration .. once you have create the tables  you need  you can populate with  the Initial data necessary for the proper functioning of the application

Comment: @scaisEdge How can the password of the ```admin``` user be set in a migration?

Comment: you can use a default password and let the user the possibility for change the password once installed ..

Comment: @scaisEdge: Is there a command to create a new user with a password? I don't want to have an user interaction here. If I can specify a default password that's fine, too.

Comment: just to avoid misunderstandings  Normally  the creation of   user (and password) for an application are  managed  by application itself ..  the user (and password) for application are not  the user/passwordc for db .. so the creation of user/password  in migration can use the same  class and function  for create an application user.  hope this is clear ..

Comment: I just saw ```User::create()``` creates a user with a given plain text password. This is what I was looking for. And if the user is called "admin" and this is specified in  ```config/web.php``` the initial admin user is created.

Comment: well seems you have found what's you need ..

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. There is an easy way to do this with Yii2 builtin migrations.

In Yii2-user there are some hooks we can use to create users.

This code has to be inserted in a migration. after creating a new migration `./yii migrate/create`, preferably after creating initial tables in the database:

```
use yii\db\Transaction;
use app\models\user\User;

public function safeUp()
{
    $transaction = $this->getDb()->beginTransaction();
    $user = \Yii::createObject([
        'class'    => User::className(),
        'scenario' => 'create',
        'email'    => 'admin',
        'username' => 'admin@example.com',
        'password' => 'mysecret',
    ]);
    if (!$user->insert(false)) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
    $user->confirm();
    $transaction->commit();
}
```

The skeleton code can be found in `./migrations/...`.

Don't forget to add database config parameters in `./config/db.php`
and the user module in `./config/console.php`

Comment: how we can use this code, if importing from excel.csv

Comment: @Joshi Take the transaction and put it in your controller. Works and is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks. can you elaborate little more, how I can do it. It will be quite helpful. if you want I can create a new question and share the link.

Comment: A new quedtion is a good idea. Here are some hints: actionUpload -> transaction ->  try -> create user per csv-line -> commit if no error -> catch for rollback.

Comment: I get some idea what you are saying, like for example for action upload, can I upload CSV file with upload interface in a form? BTW - I have created the question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511927/yii2-import-multiple-users-from-csv-file