# Yii2 - Import Multiple users from CSV file

Tags: yii2, import-from-csv

I have two tables. one is user-table -name - user and another table named profile.

The format of csv file for user is like this:

```
first_name,last_name,username,email,phone,user_role,status,password_hash,auth_key,created_at,updated_at,key_date,reset_key,access_token
Abx,xyz ,8917111039,abca@examplemail.com,891445544,employee,10,$2y$13$jbsLKjG6YtiA1RbilUOeauAS2Zvq5fHB5xh6JnHpfVytvI56IiO32,,,,,,
Alek,buhu,7978019779,sahu_alek@examplemail.com,7978444449,employee,10,$2y$13$jbsLKjG6YtiA1RbilUOeauAS2Zvq5fHB5xh6JnHpfVytvI56IiO32,,,,,,
```

and there is separate csv file for profile.

for creating new user and profile, I am using a single file and posting the relevant values separately to user and profile table.
Now as the number of users are upwards of 1000, I am looking at importing the users in batch mode using csv file.

Another option is to dump the data directly in first user-table and then exporting and getting the user_id and then dumping it in profile table.
As I am using Mongodb with auto id field, I cannot make id field as 1,2,3,4

Another advantage I think that I won't be needed to create just one default password, instead I can create some pattern for password.

my controller code to create both profile and user is like below:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Employee();
        $user = new AddUser();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
           $user->password = $user->password;
           $user->phone = $model->official_contact;
           $user->email = $model->email;
           $user->user_role='employee';

            if ($user = $user->adduser()) {


                $user->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
                $user->reset_key = md5(time());
                $user->key_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');            
                $user->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($user->password);

            $user->username = $model->email;           

            if($user->save()){

            $model->user_id = (string)$user->_id;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            if ($model->file != '') {
                $model->employee_image = $model->file->basename . '.' . $model->file->extension;                 
            }
            $model->save();
            $dir = 'web/img/employee';  
            if ($model->employee_image != '' ) {

                if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                    mkdir($dir);
                }      

            $model->file->saveAs($dir . '/' . $model->file);
            Yii::$app->getTable->imgResize($dir, $model->employee_image, 200, 0, 1, 80);
                //Yii::$app->getTable->imgResize($dir, $model->image_thumb, 350, 0, 1, 80);
                $webpImage=Yii::$app->basePath.'/web/img/employee/'.$model->employee_image;              
                 imagewebp(imagecreatefromjpeg($webpImage), $dir.'/'.basename($model->employee_image,'.jpg').'.webp'); 
            }
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => (string)$model->_id]);
        }
    }
}
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'user'=> $user,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: if the number of users are going to increase i would strongly advise you **NOT** to use ActiveRecord as it would be a resource killer and will crash you should instead go for the `Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder->batchInsert()` to generate the `$sql` statement and then use the `Yii::$app->db-->createdCommand($sql)->execute()` to insert the records. Remember none of the events are triggered when using the batchinserts so you might have to take care of that part yourself if you have any nin the `User` model

Comment: for generating passwords you can simply use the provided `Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash('pass12345');` and email the user with the password and instructions to update it, or you can use the `Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString()` an use it inside the password hash function instead of the `pass12345`